# How to Change SharePoint 2010 Project from Sandboxed Solution to Farm Solution

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I created a new sharepoint project in Visual studio 2010 and by mistake it was sandboxed solution, after finishing my development its wont build because i am adding items to controltemplates and its saying i need to have the project as farm solution, so how to change th eproject type ?

Answer (score 32):

Ok, Found it its a Project property so you need to select you project then in the properties pane (F4) you will find a property (SandBoxedSolution).

[image: Sandboxed solutions]

Answer (score 2):

If you install your sandboxed solution as a farm solution, it will work as a farm solution

Answer (score 2):

In the Properties Panel you can find a Property named as sandbox Solution, for your project it will be set to true.through the drop down option set it as false which will convert your solution to Farm solution